# The requested URL was not found on this server .htacess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to rewrite URL like:

```
example.com/speciality_details.php?id=23&name=ent
```

TO

```
example.com/specialities/23/ent
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This is my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^doctor/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)$ doctor_details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/specialities/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)$ speciality_details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

The first `RewriteRule` working but the second one is not working

Please help me to know what the problem is. How should I rewrite the code?

Comment: in .htaccess you have mentioned specialities where as in your url you have added speciality. Your rewrite rule is not matching your URL hence you are getting 404 error

Comment: @Bhavik Sorry I didn't get you can you please explain

Comment: `RewriteRule  ^/specialities/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)$` - this is your rewrite rule which you have written. So your URL should be `example.com/specialities/23/ent` OR your RewriteRule should be `RewriteRule  ^/speciality/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)$`

Comment: thank you I have changed to  example.com/specialities/23/ent  this but still, it shows not found

Comment: Please update/edit your question with the changes you have made to the URL (otherwise other readers are going to see the same mistakes). Also please include your complete .htaccess file with these directives in place (it’s likely you have a conflict).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^/specialities/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)$ speciality_details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
> ```

Just as in the first rule (which is "working"), you should not be matching a slash prefix on the URL-path. And the preceding *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) is superfluous, since a URL of the form `/specialities/23/ent` could not possibly match a physical file (could it?).

In `.htaccess`, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash since the directory-prefix (that always ends with a slash) has already been removed.

So, the rule should look like the following instead (and no `RewriteCond` directive):

```
RewriteRule ^specialities/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)$ speciality_details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

This would match a URL of the form `example.com/specialities/23/ent`, as per your example. And assumes the file being rewritten to is `speciality_details.php` in the document root.

The `NC` (`nocase`) flag should also be superfluous, unless you are expecting mixed case versions of `sPeCiAlItIeS`? But if you are then that is better resolved with a redirect since the rewrite would potentially result in a duplicate content (SEO) issue.

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing.

Although, from your earlier question edits it looks like you had already tried this without the slash prefix, but at the time you had `/speciality/23/ent`, not `/specialities/23/ent` as the example request URL - which would obviously not match.